# Drop a range of variables in SAS

Tags: sas

I currently have a dataset with 200 variables. From those variables, I created 100 new variables. Now I would like to drop the original 200 variables. How can I do that?

Slightly better would be, how I can drop variables 3-200 in the new dataset.

sorry if I was vague in my question but basically I figured out I need to use --.
If my first variable is called first and my last variable is called last, I can drop all the variables inbetween with (drop= first--last);

Thanks for all the responses.

Answer (score 6):

As with most SAS tasks, there are several alternatives.  The easiest and safest way to drop variables from a SAS data set is with PROC SQL.  Just list the variables by name, separated by a comma:

```
proc sql;
   alter table MYSASDATA
      drop name, age, address;
quit;
```

Altering the table with PROC SQL removes the variables from the data set in place.

Another technique is to recreate the data set using a `DROP` **option**:

```
data have;
   set have(drop=name age address);
run;
```

And yet another way is using a `DROP` **statement**:

```
data have;
   set have;
   drop name age address;
run;
```

Comment: Of course, if you have fewer variables that you want to *keep* than *drop*, and you want to use one of these techniques where you have to explicitly name them in code, you'd want to use a `KEEP` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Lots of options - some 'safer', some less safe but easier to code.  Let's imagine you have a dataset with variables ID, PLNT, and x1-x200 to start with.

```
data have;
id=0;
plnt=0;
array x[200];
do _t = 1 to dim(x);
x[_t]=0;
end;
run;

data want;
set have;
*... create new 100 variables ... ;
*option 1:
drop x1-x200; *this works when x1-x200 are numerically consecutive;
*option 2:
drop x1--x200; *this works when they are physically in order on the dataset - 
                only the first and last matter;
run;
```

*Or, do it this way.  This would also work with SQL ALTER TABLE.  This is
the safest way to do it.;

```
proc sql;
select name into :droplist separated by ' ' from dictionary.columns
where libname='WORK' and memname='HAVE' and name not in ('ID','PRNT');
quit;

proc datasets lib=work;
modify want;
drop &droplist.;
quit;
```

Comment: I didn't think you could drop variables in PROC DATASETS, that procedure is normally used to amend the descriptor portion of a dataset.  Has there been a change in a later version of SAS?

Comment: @Keith You are correct; one cannot drop variables using PROC DATASETS.

Answer (score 2):

If all of the variables you want to drop are named so they all start the same (like `old_var_1`, `old_var_2`, ..., `old_var_n`), you could do this (note the colon in drop option):

```
data have;
set have(drop= old_var:);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data want;
    set have;
    drop VAR1--VARx;
run;
```

Would love to know if you can do this by position.
Definitely works with variable names separated by double dash (--).

Answer (score 0):

I have some macros that would allow this [here](https://github.com/brendanjodowd/SAS/blob/master/brendan_macros.sas)
You could run that whole set of macros, or just run `list_vars()`, `is_blank()`, `num_words`, `find_word`, `remove_word`, `remove_words` , `nth_word()`.

Using these it would be:

```
%let keep_vars = keep_this and_this also_this;
%let drop_vars = %list_vars(old_dataset);
%let drop_vars = %remove_words(&drop_vars  , &keep_vars);

data new_dataset (drop = &drop_vars );
  set old_dataset;
 /*stuff happens*/
run;
```

This will keep the three variables `keep_this and_this also_this` but drop everything else in the old dataset.